# Jquery tools Overlay CSS Conflict, Image positioned under the overlay

Tags: css, jquery-tools

First here's what I'm using and trying to do:

the minimal setup for this effect:
flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html

then the Apple Leopard Preview Effect:
flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html

Now here's the page I'm having the issue with
http://gentle-mist-64.heroku.com/pictures

My Issue:
when I click on an image the picture shows under the overlay and to the right side,

This has to be a conflict between my CSS positioning to the the plugin positioning.

when I try this on a blank page with no layout, it works just fine.

my layout css:

```css
body {
  background: url('/images/background.jpg');
}

#image_stage {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 900px;
  height: 520px;
}

#image_inside_stage {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 27px;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 725px;
  top: 4px;
}

#see_through_box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.66;
  -moz-opacity: 0.66;
  filter:alpha(opacity=66);
  width: 665px;
  height: 432px;
  margin: 45px;
  z-index: 99;

  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;

  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.inner_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  z-index: 99;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Anyone please help. I want this plugin to work. This is so much better than just a light box plugin. I have used the plugin across my entire website and would like to keep on using it.

I appreciate any input, thanks.
Ami

Comment: If you're using FireFox, can you leverage FireBug to see what the computed styles are when open in the browser?  This may help you to understand what really contributes to your styling.  If all else fails, you can sprinkle a few !important clauses into your own CSS declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that entirely for jquery tool, it is very important NOT to place the jquery tools element in a parent element that is absolutly positioned.

you can simply put the window, scrollable, or whatever out side the absolute parent.

best to position with floats were you can.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try moving `photo0` and `photo1` to not be within your other divs, but instead so they're not going to be affected by any parent/inherited styles? perhaps down just before the closing `</body>` tag?

Good luck!

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing all positioning and using floats and background images instead of the calculated div boxes positons and size
so it works now
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that clue! I had a similar issue and ultimately found that jquery tools was writing out the overlay image at the bottom of the body, which meant it was getting slightly different styling than the div, which was being created in a different spot. Looking at the javascript that places the image there, I did the same thing with my overlay div

```
$('body').append($('#mortgage_card'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your elements positioned, you can actually solve it by moving the overlay element, as suggested by Funka. See this answer:

[jquery overlay wrong positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851656/jquery-overlay-wrong-positioning/2729471#2729471)